# Space specific ares in x axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below script:

```
testFigure <- ggplot(data = final_df, aes(x=final_df$`ng DNA`, 
y=final_df$`count`)) + 
geom_point(col = "darkmagenta") + ggtitle("ng VS Number") + 
xlab(expression(paste("ng"))) + ylab("Num (#)") + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color="orange", size=18, 
face="bold.italic"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="#993333", size=10, face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="#993333", size=10,face = "bold")) +  
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0,10,50,200,600))

testFigure+scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(5,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400)
```

Which generates the plot:

[image]

I'd like to space the area of the plot in the X axis, so that the lower values 0-10, but especially 0-5, will be more clear and spaced between them, while keeping the spaces of the other ticks.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: What about using the `trans` argument of `scale_x_continuous()`? For example: `data.frame(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point()+scale_x_continuous(trans="log10")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

I also noticed you have done it but in wrong axis

```
scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0,10,50,200,600))
```

but it seems that you have to do the same thing for x axe as well

```
scale_x_log10(breaks=c(0,10,50,200,600))
```

---

**Solution 2:**

```
scale_x_discrete(limits=0:5)
```

You can use scale on each axis and set a limit over it

```
   library(ggplot2)
dt<-data.frame("Name"=sample(c("A","B"),10,replace = T),
               x=sample(1:10,10),y=sample(1:10,10))

ggplot(dt, aes( x= x , y= y))+
  geom_point(stat='identity', aes(shape=Name,colour = Name))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=1:12)+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=1:12)
```

Comment: @Bella Did the solutions help you?

Comment: Yes, thank you, indeed the scale_x_log10 was also helpful for the x axis. Thank you!